# Error usando Sortablejs en React

Tags: reactjs, api, drag-and-drop, sortable

Estoy usando la libreria sortable en mi proyecto reactjs pero cuando la inserto en el componente que tiene los botones que deseo arrastrar me arroja errores, principalmente esto probando que se puedan mover los botones y luego quiero arrastrarlos de un contenedeor a otro. Si me pudieran ayuda se lo agradezco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../assets/styles/CreateReport.css';
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";

const CreateReport = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const getData_api = async () => {
    const config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cubo/api/ventas?empresa=63&periodo=202202',
      headers: {
        'token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    };
    const response = await axios(config)
    const responseData = await response.data.data
    const arrOfArray = Object.entries(responseData);
    const arraOfKeys = Object.keys(arrOfArray[1][1])
    setData(arraOfKeys)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData_api()
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <ReactSortable tag="ul" list={data} setList={setData}>
        {!data ? 'Cargando...' : data.map((item, index) => (
          <li
            key={index}
            options={{
              animation: 150,
              group: {
                name: 'lista',
                pull: 'clone'
              }
            }}
          >{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ReactSortable>
      
    </>
  )
}

export default CreateReport;
```

Estos son los botones que deseo arrastar hasta el contenedor que se muestra abajo que dice filas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que devuelve el ultimo console si haces  ``useEffect(() => {console.log(data)}, [data])``??

Comment: Creo que el problema esta porque lo estas seteando inicialmente en null, entonces eso no es un array, por lo tanto no es iterable. Podrias cambiar la condicion ``!data ? 'Cargando...' : `` por ``(data && data.length > 0) ? (map...) : ('Cargando')`` y entonces no se va a ejecutar el map hasta no tener datos en ``data``

Comment: @AgustinG. me devuelve un array de string, Que es el array que recorro para dar nombre a todos los botones que ves en la imagen.

Comment: Bien, entonces creo que mi segundo comentario es acertado. El error se da porque no reconoce a data como un array. Si cambias la condicion, el map no se deberia ejecutar hasta que data sea un array con datos adentro

Comment: @AgustinG. no amigo, sigo con el error, el mismo error.  asi ajuste el codigo...  ` ` `<div className='itemSelect'>
        {<ReactSortable tag="div" list={data} setList={setData}>
          {(data && data.length > 0) ? data.map((item, index) => (
            <button
              key={index}
              options={{
                animation: 150,
                group: {
                  name: 'lista',
                  pull: 'clone'
                }
              }}
            >{item}</button>
          )) : ('Cargando...')}
        </ReactSortable>}
      </div>` ` `

Comment: no entiendo porque envolves a <reactSortable entre llaves, y al menos hasta donde se lo que va despues de ? y : debe ir entre parentesis, ``condition ? (...) : (...)``

Comment: si podes crear un ejemplo con el error que tenes en un codesandbox lo reviso

Comment: @AgustinG. Este es el enlace de codesandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-carlos-cyg9xp?file=/src/App.jsx ahi trate de poner un ejemplo de lo que necesito, basicamente es poner clonar un boton en los contenedores de abajo. Igual te dejo mi repo de git hub para que veas el codigo bien https://github.com/Naimerith/app-aralsoft Si me puedes ayudar u orientar te agradezco mucho, no consigo solucion en internet.

Comment: pero el codigo que subiste no tiene en ninguna parte el codigo que pones en este ejemplo. CreateReport no existe en ese code sandbox. La idea es reproducir exactamente el mismo error.

Comment: @AgustinG. Es que ya el error lo solvente, Ahora mi problema esta en que la libreria  no funciona, porque cuando intento clonar no hace nada, por eso te comparti mi repo

Comment: @AgustinG. Aqui pido ayuda para eso que te comento.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/562107/253602